# libGDX: How to change color palette in texture region?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I'm trying to simulate retro arcade games , and the first problem i got is how to simulate a color palette , in order to have indexed textures and color cycling , having a limited palette.

Some points to use shaders to do it (change color at runtime) , but the problem is that it seems to have an high comp cost (I'm trying to use it in android phones).

Anyway i've been seeing some arcade simulators that seems to resolve this tipe of problem.

Any idea of how are they doing it? , Or any alternative different from having distinct colored textures?

Comment: "but the problem is that it seems to have an high comp cost." You're making a retro game; how can you *possibly* care? You can't be throwing that much visually at it, so what's the problem?

Comment: Well, the nice thing about shaders is they offload all that processing to the GPU, which can do it quite quickly...

Comment: @NathanMonteleone Then you are telling me that extracting color from a palette for each pixel is not a big cost for it?

Comment: @NicolBolas the problem comes cause i don't know if exist a better way to do it. I want to use it in android phones , then , the cheaper energy and comp , the happier the user is.

Comment: @a-quiroga Yep! GPU hardware is streamlined to do this sort of thing very quickly.